# Using Matlab to multiply two vectors using a for-loop

Tags: matlab, loops, multiplication

There is a very fundamental Matlab issue that I am missing here. My actual application is much different than this, but the following simplified example outlines the problem I am having.

```
function [x] = test(y,h)
   x = zeros(1,5);

    for iteration = 1:5
        partialSum = 0;
        for i=1:5, j=1:5;
            partialSum = partialSum + x(i)*h(j);
        end

       x(iteration) = partialSum;
    end

end
```

Assuming I do not want to vectorize this implementation, how do I properly selectively multiply two aribitrary indices from within two vectors? The above code will throw the following error because *partialSum* is not an accumulated scalar as I intended it to be.

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is arbitrarily index into each vector `x` and `y`, calculate the `scalar` result equivalent to the product of the two scalars, and keep a running sum.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need 1 index variable:

```
for i = 1:5
    partialSum = partialSum + x(i)*h(i);
end
```

EDIT: If you need i and j to be offset, try this:

```
offset = 17; % for example
for i = 1:5
    partialSum = partialSum + x(i)*h(i+offset);
end
```

EDIT2: The most general option

```
x_indices = [1 2 17 42 900];
h_indices = [3 7 29 401 1000];
for i = 1:5
    partialSum = partialSum + x(x_indices(i))*h(h_indices(i));
end
```

Comment: For this case. How could this be done if `i` was not equal to `j`?

Comment: you could make the second index any function of i that you wanted, `2*i`, `i^2`...unless there is truly no pattern, there should be a way to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

Try two nested `for` loops:

```
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        partialSum = partialSum + x(i)*h(j);
    end
end
```

Your code assigns `j=1:5` in every iteration of `i`. (The first sentence in the *Description* section of the [`for` manpage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) describes this usage)

**Edit: Incrementing two variables**
In the case that both variables are to be incremented in the same loop, use one loop adding an offset to `i` and `j` (assuming that they can be different). If they are always the same, just use one variable.

```
i = 1;
j = 1;
for offset=0:4
    partialSum = partialSum + x(i + offset) * h(j + offset);
end

for i=1:5
    partialSum = partialSum + x(i) * h(i);
end
```

Comment: This is what I want to do, except I want both `j` and `i` to increment at each iteration.

Comment: Well, my initial problem was exactly as you stated regarding the second variable of the loop. I was able to discern a pattern that I could use to reduce the implementation to a single loop. I was pulling from my *c-like* loop formations.